# Using jquery and regular javascript to open a print window for a Div with a CMS that doesn't allow media query stylesheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been struggling with this one for several weeks, and have found many helpful clues through past questions here, but have been unable to patch together a workable solution.

On my website, I have a scrolling sidebar about 350x320 that I want to have its own Print functionality. It is contained within a Div. What I have is a print button within the sidebar, that pops open a print window.

Something unique about this problem, is that the CMS we use does not allow "media-query" specific stylesheets, so no Print stylesheet!

What I am having trouble doing, is the syntax of, I think jquery's "$css()" function to have inserted within the this jquery callback function on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a.printText").click(function(){
            w=window.open('','_blank','width=1024,height=768,scrollbars=1,location=0,menubar=0')
            w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css">');
            w.document.write("<h2>{$node.name}</h2>");
            w.document.write("<h3>{$node.data_map.dek.content.output.output_text}</h3>" + "<p>By {attribute_view_gui attribute=$node.data_map.instructors}</p>");
            w.document.write($('#descIntro').html());       
            /*w.print();
            w.close();*/
        });
        });
</script>
```

The line "w.document.write('');" does not work, it's a workaround I thought might work.

The styles below I would need to "inject" into the above callback.

```
body {
    color: #000;
    font: 400 12px/19px Palatino, Georgia, serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 15px 20px;
}

h2 {
    color: #3d3d3d;
}
h3 {
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul, ol {
    margin: 3px 0 3px 20px;
}
.sidebarText {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 7px auto;
    padding: 1px 12px 8px;
    width: 500px;
}

.sidebarText + h3 {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

I'm sure this is really easy, but since it is so specific I am sure someone has the 5 second answer  out there.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One technique is you have a dummy print document that points to **its own stylesheet** (aka, your print stylesheet). Load the dummy doc into a hidden iframe, use jQuery to copy the contents into the dummy doc's body, then print from the iframe.